# RoboHelp Table of Contents not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, robohelp

Have RoboHelp script files addressed the inability to access xml files in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you choose an Adobe AIR single-source layout, but choose **Browser based Help** as the **Output Type**, assuming you want HTML Help.

Answer (score 0):

It browser from local file or webSite?

if access by local file chrome will run by commandline

--allow-file-access-from-files in the command line